# R data.table Efficiently Assign Grouping Viable by Logical Conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, apply, lapply

I have some chart data that contains a location ID and GRID ID as well as the actual data. There can be multiple locations in the same grid but some grids only have one location. I need to assign each location ID a page number based on the criteria each page only contain data for the same grid ID and that a maximum of 4 locations can be plotted on each page. Example data and my solution are below. My way seems clunky I would be curious to know if anyone has a `data.table` or `dplyr` way of doing this.

**Data**

```
Sol3<-structure(list(Location = c("29N05W21H001M", "29N05W33A004M", 
                                  "29N04W20A001M", "29N04W20A002M", "29N04W20A003M", "29N04W20A004M", 
                                  "29N04W28D001M", "29N05W14L001M", "28N04W04P001M", "27N04W05G002M", 
                                  "27N04W34P001M", "29N03W18M001M", "29N04W15E002M", "29N04W35B001M", 
                                  "27N03W20C001M", "27N04W25Q001M", "27N04W35E001M", "26N03W17B001M", 
                                  "26N04W25J001M", "25N03W19N001M", "27N03W10B001M", "27N03W16K003M", 
                                  "27N02W31C001M", "27N03W23D001M", "25N03W10L001M", "25N03W10L002M", 
                                  "25N03W10L003M", "25N03W10L004M", "25N03W10L005M", "25N03W11B001M", 
                                  "25N03W11B002M", "25N03W11B003M", "27N02W30C002M", "27N02W30C003M", 
                                  "26N02W14G001M", "26N02W15C001M", "26N02W16C001M", "26N02W17E001M", 
                                  "26N02W21Q001M", "26N02W29R001M", "25N02W09G001M", "25N02W21B001M", 
                                  "24N02W02E001M", "24N02W12P001M", "24N02W23G001M", "25N02W34K001M", 
                                  "24N01W05J003M", "24N01W05Q002M", "25N01W32P001M", "24N01W18N001M", 
                                  "24N02W25G001M"), G_ID = c("C-2", "C-2", "D-2", "D-2", "D-2", 
                                                             "D-2", "D-2", "D-2", "D-3", "D-4", "D-5", "E-2", "E-2", "E-2", 
                                                             "E-4", "E-4", "E-4", "E-5", "E-5", "E-6", "F-4", "F-4", "F-5", 
                                                             "F-5", "F-6", "F-6", "F-6", "F-6", "F-6", "F-6", "F-6", "F-6", 
                                                             "G-4", "G-4", "G-5", "G-5", "G-5", "G-5", "G-5", "G-5", "G-6", 
                                                             "G-6", "G-7", "G-7", "G-7", "G-7", "H-7", "H-7", "H-7", "H-8", 
                                                             "H-8"), G_N = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                                                             6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 
                                                                             12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
                                                                             14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                         -51L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = "<pointer: 0x0c632498>")
```

**Solution**

```
library("data.table") #Working with data.table object
Sol3$Pagenumber<-NA
Sol3$Pagenumber[1]<-1
for(n in 2:length(Sol3$Location)) {
if(Sol3$G_ID[n-1]!=Sol3$G_ID[n]) Sol3$Pagenumber[n]<-Sol3$Pagenumber[n-1]+1 else Sol3$Pagenumber[n]<-Sol3$Pagenumber[n-1]
if(n>=5) {if(Sol3$G_ID[n-4]==Sol3$G_ID[n]) Sol3$Pagenumber[n]<-Sol3$Pagenumber[n-4]+1}
}
Sol3$Pagenumber #Desired Result
```

Comment: When I run your code I get `Error in if (Sol3$G_ID[n - 1] != Sol3$G_ID[n]) Sol3$Pagenumber[n] <- Sol3$Pagenumber[n -  : 
  argument is of length zero`. What exactly is your desired result? (`Sol3$Pagenumber`)

Comment: I can get your code to run if I replace all `$G_ID` with `$PG`, is that the right thing to do?

Comment: @RonakShah @r2evans I've resolved some error in the example data. I used `dput` to grab it from my system but I had to put the <> symbols in quotes to get it to work correctly. Now the code I provided works at least for myself.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

### base R

```r
k <- 6
Sol3$Page2 <-
  Sol3$PG +
  cumsum(
    zoo::rollapplyr(Sol3$PG, k,
                    function(z) length(z) == 6 && z[1] != z[k] && all(z[-1] == z[k]),
                    partial = TRUE)
  )
Sol3
#          Location    PG Pagenumber Page2
#            <char> <int>      <num> <int>
#  1: 29N05W21H001M     1          1     1
#  2: 29N05W33A004M     1          1     1
#  3: 29N04W20A001M     2          2     2
#  4: 29N04W20A002M     2          2     2
#  5: 29N04W20A003M     2          2     2
#  6: 29N04W20A004M     2          2     2
#  7: 29N04W28D001M     3          3     3
#  8: 29N05W14L001M     3          3     3
#  9: 28N04W04P001M     3          3     3
# 10: 27N04W05G002M     4          4     4
# 11: 27N04W34P001M     5          5     5
# 12: 29N03W18M001M     6          6     6
# 13: 29N04W15E002M     6          6     6
# 14: 29N04W35B001M     6          6     6
# 15: 27N03W20C001M     7          7     7
# 16: 27N04W25Q001M     7          7     7
# 17: 27N04W35E001M     7          7     7
# 18: 26N03W17B001M     8          8     8
# 19: 26N04W25J001M     8          8     8
# 20: 25N03W19N001M     9          9     9
# 21: 27N03W10B001M    10         10    10
# 22: 27N03W16K003M    10         10    10
# 23: 27N02W31C001M    11         11    11
# 24: 27N03W23D001M    11         11    11
# 25: 25N03W10L001M    12         12    12
# 26: 25N03W10L002M    12         12    12
# 27: 25N03W10L003M    12         12    12
# 28: 25N03W10L004M    12         12    12
# 29: 25N03W10L005M    13         13    13
# 30: 25N03W11B001M    13         13    13
# 31: 25N03W11B002M    13         13    13
# 32: 25N03W11B003M    13         13    13
# 33: 27N02W30C002M    13         14    14
# 34: 27N02W30C003M    13         14    14
# 35: 26N02W14G001M    14         15    15
# 36: 26N02W15C001M    14         15    15
# 37: 26N02W16C001M    14         15    15
# 38: 26N02W17E001M    14         15    15
# 39: 26N02W21Q001M    15         16    16
# 40: 26N02W29R001M    15         16    16
# 41: 25N02W09G001M    15         16    16
# 42: 25N02W21B001M    15         16    16
# 43: 24N02W02E001M    16         17    17
# 44: 24N02W12P001M    16         17    17
# 45: 24N02W23G001M    16         17    17
# 46: 25N02W34K001M    16         17    17
# 47: 24N01W05J003M    17         18    18
# 48: 24N01W05Q002M    17         18    18
# 49: 25N01W32P001M    17         18    18
# 50: 24N01W18N001M    18         19    19
# 51: 24N02W25G001M    18         19    19
#          Location    PG Pagenumber Page2
```

The `k <- 6` is specific to your `n-4` reference: since you care if a `PG` is repeated more than 4 times (looking 5 back), then we need `k` to be at least 5. However, if we only looked 5 back, then we would detect the 5th, 6th, 7th, etc ... which would incrementally increase the new value. To block this, we catch when it repeats the 5th time, where 5 of the 6 are identical, but still different from the 1st in the window.

Basically, the rolling window looks like:

```
#  [1]  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  4  5  6  6  6  7  7  7  8  8  9 10 10 11 11 12
        ^  `-----------'
        |  if these five are the same value,
        |  and this value is different from the first --,
        |                                                |
         `----------------------------------------------'
           then we return a TRUE (effectively a 1)
```

Looking later in the sequence,

```
# [26] 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 18
             ^--`------------'
  the window of len six has one 12 and five 13s,
  the last five are all the same (trigger), and different from the first (trigger),
  and for safe keeping (since we need partial=TRUE), the length of the vector
  is six (trigger)
```

When the window shifts one to the right, however

```r
# [26] 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 17 17 17 18
                ^--`------------'
  the last five are the same (trigger), but the first is not different (NO trigger)
```

The window itself produces a sequences of logicals. Within `cumsum`, they are converted to `integer` and end up incrementing as needed.

### data.table

Since you tagged [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), here you go, though it seems a little anticlimactic.

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(Sol3)[, Page2 := PG +
                cumsum(
                  zoo::rollapplyr(PG, k,
                                  function(z) length(z) == 6 && z[1] != z[k] && all(z[-1] == z[k]),
                                  partial = TRUE)
                ) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution, where you first make a page number by PG using its position `row_number()` within the group, then use it as second grouping variable. Page number is then just the group id.

```r
Sol3 %>% 
  group_by(PG) %>%
  mutate( PageInGroup = floor( ( row_number() - 1 ) / 4 ) ) %>%
  group_by( PageInGroup, .add = TRUE ) %>%
  mutate( PageNum = cur_group_id() )
```